# Who is this (Haredi) Rabbi?

Tags: minhag

Who is this Rabbi?

[image: An elderly man, wearing a gold-and-black-colored Chassidic-style jacket and a flat-brimmed black hat, clean-shaven, with white hair falling below his chin on either side of his face]

This is a still taken from the beginning of a documentary on Haredi jews in Jerusalem: [The Anti-zionist Jews of Jerusalem](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=kTmw9F9f-2c#t=64)

I am curious to learn who this Rabbi is, why he is dressed this way and what kind of festivity we are witnessing here?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12419/which-hasidic-rabbi-has-no-beard-and-what-is-the-story

Comment: This question's been seen by a number of established users and has no closure votes, so I won't close it unilaterally, but it really seems to be off-topic. One of our standard closure reasons is: "Questions... about history or news of... Jewish individuals..., except as related to Judaism, are off-topic." See also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473. Pinging @Yishai just because I can.

Comment: @msh210, I think the last paragraph makes it on topic ("why is he dressed this way and what kind of festivity"). In this case, I would also think knowing who it is allows someone to further investigate those matters.

Comment: @Raffael - I edited your question, as a mark of respect we don't refer to important Rabbis as GUYS!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He is the [Kaliver Rebbe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Mendel_Taub).

> [Rabbi] Menachem Mendel Taub (born 1923) is the Rebbe of the Kaliv Hasidic dynasty. Born in Transylvania in 1923, he is seventh in a direct paternal line to the founder of the dynasty, Rabbi Yitzchak Izak of Kaliv, a disciple of the Rebbe Reb Elimelech of Lizhensk.

An extremely talented Rabbi who recently moved his headquarters from Bnei Braq to Jerusalem. He speaks quite a few languages, and as a survivor of Auschwitz, he regularly speaks passionately about the Holocaust and Jewish unity. As a twin, Dr Mengele experimented on him and his sister (who didn't survive).

As a Chassidic Rebbe, he regularly conducts tischen where his Chassidim will join him for his meal. This particular picture is likely on Tu B'Shvat when Rebbes are known to distribute fruit.

And, video caption aside, he is NOT anti-Zionist!

**UPDATE**: The Kaliver Rebbe passed away in Jerusalem, on Nisan 23, 5779 [April 28, 2019] (aged 95–96).

Comment: As a chasidic rebbe, he wears a variety of colorful silk coats on various festive occasions.

Comment: And he is "clean-shaven" because the Nazis pulled out his beard from the roots.

Comment: @ YEZ I've heard that many a time, though don't believe it's true. Likely the experiments stunted his growth, though.

Comment: @Zvi I actually heard it from him.  I met him about 14 years ago.  It is also true the rumor that he composes tunes to the posuk "Shema Yisroel" on the spot - he did so while we were there.

Comment: @YEZ In that case I stand corrected. Many years ago he tried instituting that everyone add the 6 words of the Pasuk of Shema to be said after Aleinu. He even published a 'Shema Yisrael Siddur'. The 6 words, he maintained, were to remind Jews of the 6 Million Jews. Other Rabbis didn't give their approval, feeling that we shouldn't edit the Siddur.

Comment: @Zvi I actually want to qualify that I don't speak Yiddish and at the time did not speak Hebrew well enough, and it's possible something got lost in translation.  But that is how I have the experience in my head.

Comment: @YEZ, considering the kinds of experiments Mengele (_yimach sh'mo_) did and the kinds of things that can cause non-growth of a beard, and especially because (as this answer notes) "he was unable to have children as a result", I wonder whether (but I don't assume) he said it was pulled out as a euphemism.

Comment: @msh210 According to the Wikipedia article cited (and its Hebrew counterpart) " Because of "chemical burning experiments", he is unable to grow facial hair".

Comment: @Zvi - where did you get the "twin" info from? it's not in the WP article you cite.

Comment: I heard this growing up. When I studied in Israel, I used to frequesnt his Shul from time to time, intrigued by his 'Kiruv' nature and special background. I found him to be particularly warm.

Comment: @Zvi in Nusach 'Edot haMizraẖ, they say Shema' after 'Aleinu. Also, why should he, as a chossid, have a problem with changing the siddur? That's exactly what the chassidim have done! Why else would there be a Nusach Sfard?

Comment: @Noach He wasn't the one who had a problem with changing the Siddur. Others did. Read my comments again. Nusach sefard pre-dates the Chassidim..

Comment: @Zvi, and most of the achronim opposed it until the acceptance of the chassidim. For Israeli Ashkenazi rabbanim, who in general accept Nusach Sfard, to oppose the Kaliver Rebbe's Shema siddur is complete hypocrisy IMO.

Comment: [Israelis mourn death of beloved rabbi who survived Holocaust, helped rebuild Jewish people](https://worldisraelnews.com/israelis-mourn-death-of-beloved-rabbi-who-survived-holocaust-helped-rebuild-jewish-people)