# Who is the Veretzky Rebbe that's been coming up everywhere?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, tzibur-community, communities

I've been seeing videos and things everywhere with this rebbe who I've never heard of before named the Veretzky Rebbe. Seems he's been popping up over the past six or so months especially, and I used to live in Monsey in chussidville and I've never heard of him. I don't want any loshon horo here, just stam information about him and his chassidis.

Comment: Whoever he is, most likely his ancestors are from [Nyzhni Vorota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyzhni_Vorota) and he is no doubt related to the late [Rav Aron Tzvi Landau ztz''l](http://www.ohrshraga.org/yeshiva), also known as the Veretzkier Rov.

Comment: @mbloch Eh, maybe not. I still don't know exactly who the Veretzky Rebbe is. But [here](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/356564/dont-miss-this-opportunity-to-receive-a-bracha-from-the-holy-tzaddik-the-veretzky-rebbe-shlita-many-have-experienced-miracles-2.html) is an article about him and [a discussion](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/veretzky) about him as well. Not to mention this question is off-topic, as it is about a Jewish individual, which is clearly against our site policy.

Comment: He's in Bnei Brak, not Brooklyn.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I must've missed that. I figured this came under community as it's about a rebbe rather than just any other Yid

Comment: @yyb896 Yup, that's why I said he must be _related_ to the Veretzkier Rov, who lives in Lakewood I believe.

Comment: @yyb896 Well maybe I got you on a good start to figuring out who he is with my links, I hope. Don't delete yet though until the mods do; we've had a few exceptions come through, like [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12419/which-hasidic-rabbi-has-no-beard-and-what-is-the-story/12454#12454), or [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43749/who-is-this-haredi-rabbi/43750#43750) (about the same Rebbe actually!).

Comment: @ezra Thank you. Yeah, I'm just curious about him and his chassidis and whatnot. Different approaches are intriguing, if they are different, that is.

Comment: @yyb896 Just because he's a Rebbe doesn't mean he has a living Chasidus. Consider the Sudiklover Rebbe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69149/discussion-between-ezra-and-yyb896).

Comment: @mbloch I formed an answer. See below.

Comment: Here you go!! Well done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Veretzky Rebbe you speak of is [Rabbi Yitzchak Isaac Labin](http://www.thelakewoodscoop.com/news/2017/05/veretzky-rebbe-to-visit-lakewood.html) of Bnei Brak. His father is [Rabbi Naftali Tzvi Labin of Ziditchov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naftali_Tzvi_Labin_of_Ziditshov). They are both descendants of Rabbi Yissachar Berish Eichenstein of Veretsky, author of [Malbush L'Shabbos V'Yom Tov](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/37501).

Additionally, Veretsky is the Yiddish name for the town of [Nyzhni Vorota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyzhni_Vorota) in Ukraine, as you can see from [this article](https://yi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%A6%D7%A7%D7%99) from the Yiddish Wikipedia titled ווערעצקי.